# postprocessor-args in youtube-dl is not working when downloading certain part of youtube video through command line

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I am trying to crop a youtube video before downloading and store it into a directory. So I searched online and found a command from this website
https://ostechnix.com/download-a-portion-of-youtube-video-with-youtube-dl-and-ffmpeg/

I used the following command in my cmd(navigated to specific directory)

```
youtube-dl --postprocessor-args "-ss 00:01:00 -to 00:02:00" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dc7I-i7sPrg"
```

But it downloaded the entire video without cropping it.
When I executed the command, I got the output like this and an mp4 file in my directory

```
[youtube] dc7I-i7sPrg: Downloading webpage
[youtube] dc7I-i7sPrg: Downloading MPD manifest
[download] Destination: Launch Web Browsers In Kiosk Mode Full Screen-dc7I-i7sPrg.mp4
[download] 100% of 5.55MiB in 00:01
```

Please inform me if I have missed out any crucial information.

Comment: Do you have ffmpeg in your system's PATH? Youtube-dl utilizes ffmpeg as its post-processor and feeds it those arguments. Try running the ffmpeg command as detailed in your link's examples and see what happens.

Comment: Also, by using the --postprocessor-args option, youtube-dl will download the whole video and trim it after-the-fact. If you want to only download part of the video, use the --external-downloader-args option with youtube-dl (see the link you posted).

Comment: Hey, FFmpeg is not installed is not added to my system path, but instead of downloading from their webpage(FFmpeg's) and adding it's path is there any way I can do this in python script

Comment: Not really... FFmpeg is the simplest solution. You don't need to call ffmpeg yourself, youtube-dl will do it for you. If you are a Linux user, ffmpeg should be available from your package manager. If you're on macOS, I'd recommend installing it with homebrew.

Comment: I have installed FFmpeg and added it to my env vars. It's working well now. Thanks for the help.